# Problema para conectarse en VPN con forclient

Tags: vpn

Este es el error que tengo "No se puede establecer la conexión VPN. El servidor VPN puede ser inalcanzable". Mi sistema operativo es windows 10 y estoy usando FortiClient, ademas ingresar todos los datos bien para la conexión. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: Tendrías que detallar un poco más que es lo que estás haciendo, ya que los detalles de conexión a lo mejor no sea lo más apropiado compartir por este medio.

Comment: Toda la configuración de la nueva conexión VPN esta bien ingresado, ademas de tener el puerto que uso abierto. Ademas esta es la primera conexión VPN que hago.

Comment: Validates que la configuracion de conexion es ssl o ipsec dependiendo de la configuracion en el forrtinet?

Comment: Tenemos que asumir que algo esta sucediendo equivocadamente en alguna de las partes, de otra manera, cómo quieres que se te ayude?, no tenemos datos, conexión, pruebas...